# How to retrieve Twilio my One to one private chat channel listing in android and IOS

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am creating Chatting platform using Twilio api, I am able to create one to one chat with other user by creating channel. This is how am giving my channel name

`POD_Direc_Chat_Myid_OtherUserId`

now my Questions is How can I find all channels where this string exist `"POD_Direc_Chat_Myid"` so that I can get all my private channel in one screen.

Comment: Is there any api by which we can search  Channel list by both user id and friendly name together in one call ?